# how to attach custom event handlers in react?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a SelectBox component created in React which I want other developers to reuse in their code. The SelectBox will have the same options every time it is reused, but I want developers to have their own custom event-handlers on the onChange event.

My code is as shown below:

```
class SelectBox extends React.Component {
   updateOutput() {
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div className="select-wrap">
            <select onChange={this.updateOutput}>
               <option value="one">ONE</option>
               <option value="two">TWO</option>
               <option value="three">THREE</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render( <SelectBox />, document.querySelector( '#main' ) );
```

I want it somehow like the concept of abstract classes where the implementation of the class is dependent on whoever is extending it.

Above, I want developers to use `<SelectBox />` and implement their own `updateOutput()` method, how to do this?

Comment: Custom events do not exist (not exposed publicly) in React, hence no custom event handlers. A suggested practice is, as explained in answers below - using props.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

 class SelectBox extends React.Component {

       render() {
          return (
             <div className="select-wrap">
                <select onChange={this.props.updateOutput}>
                   <option value="one">ONE</option>
                   <option value="two">TWO</option>
                   <option value="three">THREE</option>
                </select>
             </div>
          );
       }
    }
SelectBox .propTypes = {
  updateOutput: PropTypes.func
};

    ReactDOM.render( <SelectBox updateOutput={someFunc} />, document.querySelector( '#main' ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Write your select component like this :

```
export default class Select extends React.Component {
render(){
    const { id, ...otherAttributes } = this.props;
    let selInnerStructure = this.props.dataSrc.map((element, index) => {
        return (
            <option key={index} value={element.value}>{element.displayText}</option>);
    });

    return(

        <div>
                <select className="form-control" 
                        id={id}
                        {...otherAttributes} 
                        >
                    {selInnerStructure}
                </select>
        </div>
    );      
}
```

}

and user will use Select component in their component like below:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: [
        {"value": "save", "displayText": "Value One"},
        {"value": "cancel", "displayText": "Value Two"}
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Select dataSrc={this.state.name} id="selId" 
          name="selData"
          onClick={(e) => console.log("onClick")}
          onChange={(e) => console.log("onChange")}
        />
        {/* passed other attribs also */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

by using this, user will call their own onClick, onChange events as they wish. If you set `<select onChange={this.props.updateOutput}>` like this, they tend to use onChange alone, If you don't need users to add more events the following is enough :

`<select onChange={this.props.updateOutput}>`

with your component, I have made few helpful options too, which will user can add otherAttributes too as they wish to add.

Hope this helps.

Working Demo : [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kza5y8)

Answer (score 0):

The developer need to create an event handler and pass it as a prop to . You call this prop onChange.

> onChange={this.props.onChange}

```
<select onChange={this.props.onChange}>
  <option value="one">ONE</option>
  <option value="two">TWO</option>
  <option value="three">THREE</option>
</select>
```

The developer needs to use  as below

```
<SelectBox onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} />
```